# I have to read numbers by using Scanner and for each

Tags: java

I couldn't find any hint on the internet.
almost of mention of 'for each' say "can't change value assigned on the array"
is it impossible?
my code is this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr = new int[5];
for(int i : arr)
    i = in.nextInt();
```

I want to use 'for each' and read numbers by using Scanner class 
please help me..

Comment: is there a reason you want to use for-each instead of a standard for? homework perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple `for` loop, and add the read number to the `i`-th position of the array:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr = new int[5];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

It doesn't make much sense to use the enhanced `for` loop in your particular scenario, since your array is initially empty. You can use it, however, to *iterate* over the created array, that is:

```
for (int i : arr) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: using 'for each' is impossible?

Comment: @beginner: In this particular scenario, it doesn't make much sense, since you are building an array.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this: -

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

for (int i : arr) {
    arr[i] = in.nextInt();
}
```

But as stated above by `João Silva`, you should use for-each loop only to iterate over an already initialized array, not to initialize it..

Comment: wouldn't `i` in each iteration be the value of arr[i] and not it's index?

Comment: @ColinD Correct. Since the array elements are initialized to 0, he continously updates arr[0]

Comment: O.o... What a blunder.. Thanks Colin for pointing.. Then our array must be initialized to some value initially.. ** Just saw hmjd answer's above.. And got the answer.. going to edit here..